# Loopback 4 custom error messages on models

Tags: loopback4

According to the [Loopback 4 documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Model.html), you can add a custom error message on the validation of a model like so:

```
jsonSchema: {
  maxLength: 30,
  minLength: 10,
  errorMessage:
    'name must be at least 10 characters and maximum 30 characters',
},
```

I would like to generate a custom error message in this way, but I am only getting the default error messages for the given validation. This is my code:

```
jsonSchema: {
    maxLength: 13,
    errorMessage: "Primary phone number is required and should be formatted like (XXX) XXX-XXXX",
    pattern: "[(][0-9]{3}[)] [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}",
  },
```

})

When I give it a string like "123 456-789" I get this:

> {
>       "error": {
>           "statusCode": 422,
>           "name": "UnprocessableEntityError",
>           "message": "The request body is invalid. See error object `details` property for more info.",
>           "code": "VALIDATION_FAILED",
>           "details": [
>               {
>                   "path": "/primary_phone",
>                   "code": "pattern",
>                   "message": "should match pattern \"[(][0-9]{3}[)] [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}\"",
>                   "info": {
>                       "pattern": "[(][0-9]{3}[)] [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
>                   }
>               }
>           ]
>       }
>   }

I've tried a wide variety of placement for errorMessage and fiddled around with spelling, but nothing changes the error I get. Is there something else I need to do to get these custom error messages to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loopback member Hage Yaapa informed me that this is a case of bad documentation. The missing piece is this:

```js
this.bind(RestBindings.REQUEST_BODY_PARSER_OPTIONS).to({
  validation: {
    ajvKeywords: true,
    ajvErrors: true
  }
});
```

This must be added to your application/context in order to enable the extra functionality for custom errors.

Comment: I think this would probably work for me except I've had to change to stream to accept files, so I'm not using the body parser as normal. Alas! But I think I'll just address it with documentation for the API users and leave it at that. :)